# DOMException: "String contains an invalid character" in Angular

Tags: angular

empolyee.service file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Empolyee } from './empolyee.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmpolyeeService {
  formData: Empolyee;
  constructor() { }
}
```

empdata.component file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EmpolyeeService } from 'src/app/shared/empolyee.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-empdata',
  templateUrl: './empdata.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./empdata.component.css']
})
export class EmpdataComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service:EmpolyeeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

empdata.component:

```
<form #form="ngForm">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)}="service.formData.name" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Emp Code</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.empcode" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Mobile</label>
    <input type="number"[(ngModel)]="service.formData.mobile" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Role</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.role" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-lg">
</div>
</form>
```

Model:

```
export class Empolyee {
    empid:number;
    name:string;
    empcode:string;
    mobile:number;
    role:string;
}
```

This error I have received:

> [WDS] Disconnected! vendor.js:112996:9
>
> ERROR DOMException: "String contains an invalid character" EmpdataComponent.ngfactory.js:29:12
>
> ERROR CONTEXT 
>   Object { view: {…}, nodeIndex: 8, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…} } EmpdataComponent.ngfactory.js:29:12
>
> DOMException: "String contains an invalid character" main.js:442:27

​

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are too many syntax errors in the template. Spacing and wrong bracket ending caused the error.

```
<input type="number"[(ngModel)]="service.formData.mobile" class="form-control">
```

You need a space between `type="number"` and `[(ngModel)]="service.formData.mobile"`:

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.mobile" class="form-control">
```

And also here:

```
 <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.mobile" class="form-control">
```

Replace this (Wrong bracket ending `}`):

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)}="service.formData.name" class="form-control">
```

With:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.name" class="form-control">
```